# How to avoid seeing sensitive user data in django admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, privacy-policy

I have done a django web app in which users can input some data. I have created a super user and as the admin of the app I can see the data input by users which is fine for name and not sensitive data but I do not want to be able to see their sensitive data such as health data.

I have used the `encrypt` module from `django_cryptography.fields` as follow:

```
health_data = encrypt(models.IntegerField(default=140))
```

I figured out that if I am looking at the database from external script or simple DBbrowser, it works well as I cannot see the sensitive data. But I understood that this is seamless in the django admin: in django admin page it is decrypting before it is rendered.

So I am ok with the encrypt data which is additional safety but this was not my first goal. I want to have the super user but I want that I am **not** able to see their sensitive data. Do you have any ideas ? I appreciate your time reading.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options you can modify the behaviour of the admin site for the model. Specifically if you don't want to customize which fields are shown, etc. see the `fields` attribute.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , ok appreciate. In `admin.py` in my app i have changed this `admin.site.register(MyModel)` by this  `class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): fields=(my_fields)`  with the decorator `@admin.register`  
It works well but truth is that I am not sure this is the behavior I wanted. If I am malicious I can still change the code of my app and get back the sensitive data. I know I won't do that but let's imagine I leave the administration of the whole code project to another person. I am maybe paranoiac but want to be sure I am doing right way.

Comment: "_If I am malicious I can still change the code of my app and get back the sensitive data_", you talk as if there is any possible solution to this scenario. Who can stop someone who has direct access to the code and can modify it as per their wish? They won't even need the admin site, as this is just some encryption which uses the `SECRET_KEY` or `CRYPTOGRAPHY_KEY` setting which would be clearly visible to them, not to mention they can simply query it for the shell themselves...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241363/how-to-avoid-seeing-sensitive-user-data-in-django-admin-page#comment118854094_67241363) I changed my admin code from this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

to this:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # avoid admin can see the sensitive data in admin page
    fields = ("non_sensitive_field1", "non_sensitive_field2",...,)
```

By this way I customize the rendered fields in admin page. I cannot see anymore the sensitive data from users in the admin page which is the behavior I wanted.